# Number of right cyclic shifts to give the biggest number

Tags: java, algorithm, interview-questions, time-limit-exceeded, bitwise

I am preparing to coding interview and I met this task today:

You are given 30-bit unsigned integer N. A right cyclic shift of N by K bits is the result of performing a right cyclic shift of N by one bit K times. Leading zeros may appear.

For example:

- the right cyclic shift of 9736 by one bit is 4868,
- the right cyclic shift of 9736 by two bits is 2434,
- the right cyclic shift of 9736 by eleven bits is 809500676

The number 809500676 is the largest value that can be obtained by performing a right cyclic shift of 9736.

The aim is to find integer K such that right cyclic shift of N by K bits gives the largest possible value. In example above method should return 11. 0<=N<=1073741823. Worst-case time complexity is O(log(N)).

My try should be correct value but does not meet (in my opinion, but I am not sure) time complexity.

```
    public int solution(int N) {
        long m = N;
        long max = N;
        int res = 0;
        for(int i =1;i<30;i++) {
            m=(N>>>i) & 0x3fffffff | (N<<(30-i)& 0x3fffffff);
            if(m>max) {
                max=m;
                res=i;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Can you use [assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/671815/1157100)?

Comment: Java is preferred. If you meant that...

Answer (score 2):

Your solution seems fine.
I would suggest some coding style improvements though:

- To avoid errors, avoid magic numbers, put them in constants, for example:

  - `MAX_N = 0x3fffffff`
  - `MAX_SHIFT = 30`
- The variable `m` doesn't need to be initialized before the loop. In fact, it doesn't need to be declared before the loop. Move it inside.
- `res` is not a great name to store the number of shifts to get the highest number. `shiftCount` would be better.
- `solution` is not a great name for the method to get the shift count for the highest number. `getShiftCountToHighestNum` would be better.

With the above suggestions applied, the code becomes:

```
private static final int MAX_N = 0x3fffffff;
private static final int MAX_SHIFT = Integer.toBinaryString(MAX_N).length();

public int getShiftCountToHighestNum(int N) {
    long max = N;
    int shiftCount = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX_SHIFT; i++) {
        long m = (N >>> i) & MAX_N | (N << (MAX_SHIFT - i) & MAX_N);
        if (m > max) {
            max = m;
            shiftCount = i;
        }
    }
    return shiftCount;
}
```

As for the time complexity,
I believe this is indeed \$O(\log N)\$.
The number of calculation steps is proportional to the number of bits in \$N\$, which grows much slower than \$N\$ itself.

Comment: You're replaced a magic number by a magic constant; what about `MAX_N = (1 << MAX_SHIFT) - 1`?

Comment: Good call, fixed it. Not by calculating `MAX_N` which is the given, but by setting `MAX_SHIFT` to `Integer.toBinaryString(MAX_N).length()`. Hope that's better. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. It could be done more efficiently (which doesn't matter for a constent) using something like `32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros`, but this is always a bit error-prone (the opposite direction works for me perfectly). And there's also Guava's [IntMath.log2](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/math/IntMath.html#log2(int,%20java.math.RoundingMode)).

Answer (score 2):

Just a tiny note on complexity. The complexity theory ignores constant factors and makes no sense for cases when the input can't grow without limits.

> Worst-case time complexity is O(log(N)).

This can't be. Either you work with 30 bit numbers and make 30 iterations and there's a complexity of `O(1)` as the time is fixed. Or you allow an arbitrary number of bits and then you need an algorithm dealing with it. The running time for a straightforward implementation will be something like the number of bits squared, i.e., complexity `O(log(N)**2)`. I guess, it can be optimized to the desired complexity, but that's a different task.

Answer (score 2):

Two quick things:

1. You don't have to use `long` anywhere, since everything fits in `int`.
2. `(x & MASK) | (y & MASK)` can be simplified to `(x | y) & MASK`:

   ```
       m = (N >>> i | N << (30-i)) & 0x3fffffff;
   ```